# How to prevent a program from closing when I exit the Powershell Window

Tags: powershell, background, console

The thing is: I have a Powershell Script I want to use to automate stuff by running programs (using arguments to customize their behaviour) in the background and stuff like that.

However, I want to be able to execute the script in an already-started console and then being able to close the window without the child process exiting (notice how I'm not asking for an *invisible execution* but just a *persistent one* that doesn't rely on the existence of the PS window).

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InDisconnectedSession parameter of Invoke-Command to run your code and it will complete even after the host session exists.

```
$ICArgs = @{ComputerName          = "$TargetComputer"
            ScriptBlock           = $SBCode
            InDisconnectedSession = $True}
            
Invoke-Command @ICArgs
```

Where: $TargetComputer is where you want to execute code.
$SBCode is the block of code you want to execute.

HTH